# JavaScript object assignment

Tags: javascript, json

How do I get this result?

```
{"obj1": {
    "title": "title",
    "data": [1,2,3]
},
"obj2": {
    "title": "title",
    "data": [4,5,6]
},
"obj3": {
    "title": "title",
    "data": [7,8,9]
}}
```

```js
    var obj = {title:'title'}
    var newobj = {};

    newobj.obj1 = obj;
    newobj.obj2 = obj;
    newobj.obj3 = obj;

    newobj.obj1.data = [];
    newobj.obj1.data = [1,2,3];

    newobj.obj2.data = [];
    newobj.obj2.data = [4,5,6];

    newobj.obj3.data = [];
    newobj.obj3.data = [7,8,9];

    console.log(JSON.stringify(newobj))
```

Comment: I don't even know what you want.

Comment: I want this result.  { "obj1": { "title": "title", "data": [1,2,3] }, "obj2": { "title": "title", "data": [4,5,6] }, "obj3": { "title": "title", "data": [7,8,9] } }

Comment: @mxh861001 have you looked at any tutorials about using objects?

Comment: It is showing proper when I ran code snippet...

Comment: ya it also showing correct as you want

Comment: You could literally put `var newObj =` before your *result* at the top there and have your answer

Comment: put `var result = ` in front of `{"obj1": { ... etc` - result will be the result

Comment: `newobj.obj1 = obj;
    newobj.obj2 = obj;
    newobj.obj3 = obj;` ... will result in obj1,2 and 3 all referring to the same object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning the `obj` to `newObj`'s properties. That wouldn't assign a new object to those properties which basically means that they're just referencing `obj`. And when it's just referenced, whenever you make changes to that reference, all the other places where it is referenced changes.

What you need to do is to make a copy of the `obj` and then assign it to `newObj`'s proerties. The [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) syntax in the `{}` creates a new object with `obj`'s properties.

```js
var obj = {title:'title'}
var newobj = {};

newobj.obj1 = { ...obj };
newobj.obj2 = { ...obj };
newobj.obj3 = { ...obj };

newobj.obj1.data = [1,2,3];
newobj.obj2.data = [4,5,6];
newobj.obj3.data = [7,8,9];

console.log(JSON.stringify(newobj));
```

Comment: Keep in mind that object spread (`{...obj}`) is not standard in all browsers! It is currently in stage 3 of the proposal process.

Answer (score 1):

In Js you can directly create an object using object literal notation and the beauty of it is that it allows you to define properties too..

just use

var obj = {
obj1:{
    "title": "title",
    "data": [1,2,3]
},
obj2: {
    "title": "title",
    "data": [4,5,6]
},
obj3: {
    "title": "title",
    "data": [7,8,9]
}}

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, I believe, is that you are setting newobj.obj1, obj2, and obj3 all = obj. That is done by reference, so when you update the data of each of obj1, 2, 3 you are actually updating the reference to obj and so updating them all.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, lines 8, 11 and 14 can just be removed.

Also, objects in javascript are references to a location in memory. So when you do:

```
newobj.obj1 = obj;
newobj.obj2 = obj;
newobj.obj3 = obj;
```

You are saying that newobj.obj1, newobj.obj2, newobj.obj3 are pointing to the exact same place in memory. Meaning if you modify obj1, you also modify obj2 and obj3. You need to make sure that they are unique objects like this:

```js
var newobj = {};

newobj.obj1 = {title:'title'};
newobj.obj2 = {title:'title'};
newobj.obj3 = {title:'title'};

newobj.obj1.data = [1,2,3];

newobj.obj2.data = [4,5,6];

newobj.obj3.data = [7,8,9];

console.log(JSON.stringify(newobj))
```

This is not the only way to make them unique, but the point is that they need to have their own locations in memory.

Answer (score -1):

You can do simply with constructor function

```
function DataObj(title, data) {
    this.title = title;
    this.data = data;
}

var newObj = {
    obj1: new DataObj('title', [1,2,3]),
    obj2: new DataObj('title', [4,5,6]),
    obj3: new DataObj('title', [7,8,9])
}

console.log(newObj);
```